# H2O variable importance for all discrete levels included in the model

Tags: python, h2o

I want to extract the individual categorical levels from a variable importance standpoint for a given model. There are several categorical predictors in the dataset supplied below, yet when I go to calculate feature importance, only the "whole column's" importance is shown, as opposed to the importances being broken up into something like `C1_level0: importance` and `C1_level1: importance`. How can I view the importance of the columns similar to what I'd see if I manually one-hot-encoded these discrete levels?

```
>>> import h2o
>>> h2o.init()
Checking whether there is an H2O instance running at http://localhost:54321. connected.
--------------------------  ----------------------------------------
H2O cluster uptime:         48 mins 24 secs
H2O cluster timezone:       America/Chicago
H2O data parsing timezone:  UTC
H2O cluster version:        3.20.0.5
H2O cluster version age:    6 days
H2O cluster name:           H2O_from_python_user_9znggm
H2O cluster total nodes:    1
H2O cluster free memory:    1.464 Gb
H2O cluster total cores:    8
H2O cluster allowed cores:  8
H2O cluster status:         locked, healthy
H2O connection url:         http://localhost:54321
H2O connection proxy:
H2O internal security:      False
H2O API Extensions:         XGBoost, Algos, AutoML, Core V3, Core V4
Python version:             3.6.5 final
--------------------------  ----------------------------------------
>>>
>>> df = h2o.create_frame(categorical_fraction=0.5)
Create Frame progress: |██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 100%
>>>
>>> model = H2OGradientBoostingEstimator()
>>> model.train(x=[c for c in df.columns if c != 'C1'], y='C1', training_frame=df)
gbm Model Build progress: |███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 100%
>>>
>>> model.varimp(True)
  variable  relative_importance  scaled_importance  percentage
0       C3          4448.583984           1.000000    0.255125
1       C9          4424.002930           0.994474    0.253715
2       C6          4273.684082           0.960684    0.245094
3       C4          4249.320312           0.955207    0.243697
4      C10            12.800615           0.002877    0.000734
5       C7            12.022744           0.002703    0.000689
6       C8             8.271964           0.001859    0.000474
7       C2             4.649746           0.001045    0.000267
8       C5             3.567022           0.000802    0.000205
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that you could get with H2O's GLM when using `model.std_coef_plot()`, however the expected behavior of `model.varimp(True)` is to give you each feature's importance not the importance of individual levels.

If you want to understand the relationship between an individual level and the outcome I would recommend using H2O's partial dependence plots (documentation [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/model_categories.html?#h2o.model.model_base.ModelBase.partial_plot) and [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/flow.html?#partial-dependence-plots).

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called `partial dependency plots` and you can have it from the `pdp_data = model.partial_plot(data=fi_data, cols=variable_list, plot=False, nbins=30,plot_stddev = False )` command

Inside this data table you have the information you need so after some processing you can print for each variable in the model a graph like this.

[image]

The red point represent the mean of Y and the dot the `prediction` for each level ceteris paribus